# Is there a US version of the UK Criminal Records Bureau check?

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens, criminal-records

I am a US citizen who has moved to the UK. My new employer has asked me to get a Criminal Records Bureau (CRB) check so I can work with children. Since I do not have sufficient history in the UK, my employer has also asked me to supply them with a US CRB. What is the US equivalent of a CRB check?

Comment: We've used the company similar to [this one](https://www.certifiedbackground.com/) to get them since they need to check multiple local and federal databases to get a background check.

Comment: FYI, it's now called a DBS https://www.gov.uk/disclosure-barring-service-check/dbs-barred-lists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The US does not have an easy way to get the exact equivalent of the UK CRB.

The US State Dept [has a page on this very subject](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/while-abroad/criminal-record-checks.html):

> U.S. citizens may be asked to present a “certificate of good conduct” or “lack of a criminal record” for a variety of reasons for use abroad including adoption, school attendance, employment, etc.  U.S. law enforcement authorities may not be familiar with such a procedure since it is not commonly requested in the United States.  There are a variety of options available to U.S. citizens seeking to obtain proof of their lack of a criminal record.
>
> **LOCAL POLICE CHECK**: Go to your local police department where you reside or last resided in the United States, request that the police conduct a local or state criminal records search and provide you with a document reflecting that there is no history of a criminal record...
>
> **FBI RECORDS CHECK**:  ... The FBI offers two methods for requesting your [FBI Identification Record](http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/criminal-history-summary-checks) or proof that a record does not exist...An individual requiring an apostille or authenticated copy of his/her FBI Identification Record, or any non U.S. person who wishes to request his/her FBI Identification Record must submit a request directly to the FBI CJIS Division...
>
> **AUTHENTICATION OF POLICE OR FBI CERTIFICATES OF LACK OF A CRIMINAL RECORD**:  The FBI’s CJIS Division will authenticate U.S. Department of Justice Order 556-73 fingerprint search results for international requests by placing the FBI seal and signature of a Division official on the results, if requested at the time of submission...

So it looks like the best that you can do is get Local Police (from the place where you last lived) and FBI checks. It might be good to check with your new employer to make sure that this will be sufficient *before* going through the effort of obtaining the proper documents.